# Which option should I use to allow networking between virtual machines and Internet access?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I am currently using VirtualBox 4.1.8 on Windows 7 host if it matters ;)

I want to connect 2 (or more) virtual machines together AND give them the access to Internet (so that I can get the packages etc.)
So far I have used internetworking option to allow the connection of machines but now I them also to connect to the web.

I have already added the VirtualBox' DHCP server to this network but I think somewhere in there I would have to configure gateway/DNS settings.

How can I accomplish that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest setup would be to use the bridged nic on all the vms so as to connect all your vms to the internet router, just like your physical machines.

If you don't like that option, then you need to have a router vm through which all the vm traffic to the internet should be directed to. there are router appliances you can get from some download sites, or you can build one yourself fairly easily.